# How to add line jump in a insert query on informix?

Tags: jquery, informix

I'm intending to insert a line break in a query insert on Informix. I used:  '\n' but, that is taken as a string and it doesn't accept it as a line break. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at `ifx_allow_newline` : http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1570.htm

Comment: You can also try something like: `SELECT 'Wibble' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + 'Wobble'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use PreparedStatement. There is example of this using JDBC and Jython:

```
pstm = db.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_table_prepared (txt) VALUES (?)")
try:
    for i in range(100):
        pstm.setString(1, "txt%d\nline 2\nline3" % (i))
        pstm.executeUpdate()
finally:
    pstm.close()
```